# Android map under transparent system bar

Tags: android, android-layout, android-styles, mapbox-android

I have a fairly simple layout:

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <com.mapbox.mapboxsdk.maps.MapView
        android:id="@+id/mapView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

    <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/fab"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"
        android:layout_margin="@dimen/fab_margin" />

 </FrameLayout>
```

I want the map to appear under the **completly** transparent system bars (navigation bar and status bar). To accieve this, I set the status and navigation bar color to `android:color/transparent`:

```
<style name="Theme.Lab.Map">
    <item name="android:statusBarColor">@android:color/transparent</item>
    <item name="android:navigationBarColor">@android:color/transparent</item>
    <item name="android:fitsSystemWindows">false</item>
</style>
```

But unfortunatly, the map does not appear under the system bars. Instead, the default activity backgound color is visible.
I set `fitSystemWindows` to false as it helped when I set `android:translucentStatusBar` to `true`. The problem with `translucentStatusBar` is, that the status bar is only semi translucent, not completly transparent as I want it to be.
I somehow have to tell the map - or the activity - that it can expand underneath the systembars.

**EDIT**

It could also be possible to use `translucentStatusBar` but change the transparency/opacity of the status bar. I just didn't find a way to do this.